# MySQL trigger that capitalize all letter

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I made an input box and did `text-transform: uppercase` but when the data is inserted in phpMyAdmin, it is not uppercase unless I manually capitalize each letter. I wanted to make a MySQL trigger where if data is inserted the word is uppercase automatically in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: `text-transform: uppercase` is for display purposes only. It doesn't affect the data.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT
ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.column_name = UPPER(NEW.column_name);

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE UPDATE
ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.column_name = UPPER(NEW.column_name);
```